# How to sort data by groupmenu?

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

How to sort data by `groupmenu`?

**mysql**

```
SELECT pc.pc_id, pc.pc_icon, pc.pc_parent, pcd.pcd_name, pcd.pcd_id 
FROM product_category pc 
LEFT JOIN product_category_detail pcd ON pcd.pc_id=pc.pc_id 
ORDER BY pc.pc_group, pc.pc_sort, pc.pc_id
```

[image]

**I want to show content menu**

*Ex.*

- test6
- -subtest6
- --subtest6-2
- ---subtest6-2-1
- test7

How I can query it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have unlimited sub-menu, it might be easier to use PHP to loop.

It's still easy to produce 2 levels of menu, eg

```
SELECT a.id,
FROM 
SELECT pc.pc_id, pc.pc_icon, pc.pc_parent, pcd.pcd_id,
concat(if (pc.pc_parent = 0, '', '- '), pcd.pcd_name) AS pcd_name
FROM product_category AS pc
LEFT JOIN product_category_detail AS pcd ON pcd.pc_id = pc.pc_id
```

ORDER BY pc.pc_group, pc.pc_sort, pc.pc_id

OR you might redesign the category table to have an easy and unlimited sub-menu trees:

```
pc_id
11
1122   -- kid of 11
112233 -- kid of 1122
55
66
6677   -- kid of 66
```